# IFTTT recipes with “new screenshots” condition are not triggered on OnePlus One

Tags: screenshots, ifttt

Copied from Web applications (commenter suggested it fits more here)

I made a simple IFTTT recipe, where I want each new screenshot taken to be sent to my trello board. I worked out different trello recipes well, which worked. I tried several new screenshot conditioned ifttt recipes and they did not work. Is there a way to debug IFTTT recipes somehow?

Randomly, rarely the recipe does work. But I cannot see or isolate the conditions that lead to the succesful execution of the recipe, if there are any.